# throwing UnhandledPromiseRejection even the code wrapped in try catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

I am getting UnhandledPromiseRejection error even I wrapped the code in try catch block
I using await Prmomise.all together here

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3003;

function testPromise(n) {
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        console.log(n);
        if (n > 10) {
            res(true);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                rej(n);;
            }, 1000)

        }
    });
}

function test2(n) {
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        console.log(n);
        if (n > 10) {
            res(true);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                rej(n);;
            }, 10000)

        }
    });
}
async function allCall(p) {
    await Promise.all(p);
}
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let a = [];
        let b = [];

        a.push(testPromise(1));
        await test2(1);
        a.push(testPromise(12));
        // await Promise.all(a.map(m => m.then(() => { }).catch(err => { })));
        await Promise.all(a);
        res.send('Hello World!');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err');
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send('xxxxxxxxxx!')
    }

})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I am not sure why it is throwing the error

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch().

Please explain why and how to resolve this ?

Comment: Its javascript. updated the tag

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because 2 promises are getting rejected but try/catch only handles one. The second promise is rejected but not handled.

**1st rejection:** `a.push(testPromise(1));`

**2nd rejection:** `await test2(1);`

**NOTE:**

- Both the promises are started parallel.
- try/catch only works with async/await, if you write promise inside try/catch it'll not be handled by the catch block.

  ```
  try {
      Promise.reject("Something")
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('Not here');
  }
  // Unhandled promise rejection
  ```

**Explanation:**

1. When you push a promise to an array `a.push(testPromise(1));`, it starts execution and rejects after 1 second. It goes to catch.
2. same time the second promise also started `await test2(1);` because you are not waiting for the first promise to resolve/reject. It'll get rejected after 1 second and not handled by the catch block. it'll go to catch only if you use with await. If you want to handle first rejection you have to use `.catch`. after 10 seconds second promise get rejected and handled by catch block.

**Solution**

```
const r = await testPromise(1);
await test2(1);
```

**Another solution:**

```
async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // a.push(testPromise(1));
    await test2(1);
    let a = [testPromise(1), testPromise(12)];
    await Promise.all(a);
    console.log("done");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err");
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: so in the first solution `a.push(r);' is not required ,right

Comment: @Subash correct you don't need.